# Track a moving peak on a periodic ListAnimate plot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, animation, peak-detection

I have a ListAnimate plot and I want to track the position of the peak as it moves.

Is there any way to do this which takes into account the fact that the peak of the wave moves past the window of the plot on the right hand side.

```
ListAnimate[Table[ListLinePlot[Table[Sin[2*Pi*i/100 - j], {i, 0, 100}]], {j,0,10}]]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Edit:**

The value for distance traveled should keep counting and not reset each time it passes the point it began.

Is there any way to do this which takes into account the fact that the peak of the wave moves past the window of the plot on the right hand side.

Answer (score 3):

```
ListAnimate[Table[With[{t = Table[{i, Sin[2*Pi*i/100 - j]}, {i, 0, 100}]}, 
     ListLinePlot[t, Epilog -> {Orange, PointSize[Large], Point@MaximalBy[Last][N@t]}]], 
   {j, 0, 10}]]
```

[image]

**Update:**

```
firstpeak = First@MaximalBy[Last][N@Table[{i, Sin[2*Pi*i/100]}, {i, 0, 100}]];

ListAnimate[Table[With[{t = Table[{i, Sin[2*Pi*i/100 - j]}, {i, 0, 100}]}, 
   ListLinePlot[t, 
    Epilog -> {Orange, PointSize[Large], 
      Point[currentpeak = MaximalBy[Last][N@t]]}, 
    PlotLabel -> Column[{"distance traveled by orange point", 
       ArcLength[Line[{firstpeak, First@currentpeak}]]}, 
      Alignment -> Center]]], 
  {j, 0, 10}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Is there anyway to find the total distance that the orange point "travels" during the animation and extract this separately?

Comment: @James, please see the update.

Comment: What I mean is the cumulative distance the peak travels. The value for distance traveled should keep counting and not reset each time it passes the point it began. Also, is there a way to view these values as a list and not as past of the plot label?

Comment: @James, I suggest you update your question with  the additional requirements you have posted in comments (or, better yet, post them as new questions).

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this do what you want:

```
ClearAll[values, maxValues, valuesAndMax];
values = Table[{i, Sin[2*Pi*i/100 - j]}, {j, 0, 10}, {i, 0, 100}];
maxValues = 
  Flatten[#, 
     1] & /@ (With[{max = Max[#[[;; , -1]]]}, 
       Select[#, #[[2]] == max &]] & /@ values);
valuesAndMax = Transpose[{maxValues, values}];
ListAnimate[
 ListLinePlot[#[[2]], 
    Epilog -> {Orange, PointSize -> .02, Point[#[[1]]]}] & /@ 
  valuesAndMax]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The max value is shown as an orange point that moves with the graphs.

Comment: Is there anyway to find the total distance that the orange point "travels" during the animation and extract this separately?